# why const not use when useState Varaible Declare ?? Show Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

When const identifier use to Declare useState as e.g.

```
const [counterState, setCounterState] = useState(0);
```

```
import {  useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  let count =0;
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  
  const Incrementalcount=()=>{
++count;
console.log(count);
setCounter(++counter);
}

  return (
   
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
       State counter wihtout is{count}

       <br></br>
       State counter  is {counter} 
       <br></br>

       <button onClick={Incrementalcount}> Counter </button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am trying but The State Variable Value not to updated When Clicked  ===

[image]

When Clicked To Button Then Error In Developer Tool

Show Error and in Developer Tool and Not to be increment value

[image]

Comment: *why const not use when useState Varaible Declare ?? Show Error* - what does it even mean?

Comment: When const identifier use declare for use State then Show Error but if i use let  keyword then no error to display why ??

Comment: Because `const` is constant and cannot be changed

Answer (score 1):

use `setCounter(counter + 1);` instead

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ckhm17?file=App.tsx)